# Determening the expression for a function at the radial boundary

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

In the process of dimensionalizing a conical rod subjected to pressure, I derived a system of equations in the cylindrical coordinate system:

$$ U_z(t,r,0)=A \sin(wt)\tag1$$
$$ U_r(t,0,z)=0\tag2$$
$$ U_r(t,r,z_{max})= U_z(t,r,z_{max})=0\tag3$$
$$ {\partial U_r(t,r,z)\over \partial r  }\Bigg|_{r=r_{max}}={\partial U_z(t,r,z)\over \partial z  }\Bigg|_{r=r_{max}} \tag4$$

The function $U_r(t,r,z)$ is the radial displacement and the function $U_z(t,r,z)$ is the longitudinal displacement. My goal is to derive an expression for the function $f(t,z)$ which satisfies the condition:

$$ f(t,z)=U_z(t,r_{max},z) \tag5$$

Because I failed to solve this problem, I am not even sure if it is solvable with the given first four equations I have.

My questions are:

1. Is it at all possible to determine the function $f(t,z)$ with the given input equations I have?
2. If yes, how can I do that?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So these are just a list of boundary conditions for the vector field $\vec U(t,r,z) = (U_r,U_z)$, which as you might expect do not determine $\vec U$ uniquely. For example, let $g(s)$ be any differentiable function on $[0,z_{max}]$ with $g(0) = 1, g(z_{max}) = 0,$ and $g'(z_{max}) = 0$. Then one can check that

$$ U_z(t,r,z) = A\sin(wt)g(z)$$
$$ U_r(t,r,z) = Ar\sin(wt)g'(z)$$

satisfies all of your conditions and so $f(t,z) = A\sin(wt)g(z)$ can be very different depending on the choice of $g$. Obviously more complicated constructions are possible as well. But the point is that usually boundary conditions like this are accompanied by a PDE of some sort that holds on the *interior* of the square $[0,r_{max}]\times [0,z_{max}]$ that allow us to uniquely determine the vector field.

To summarize, this problem is underdetermined (we need more information)

Comment: Thought so to. Thank you Anrew.